# How to implement listener interface in fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to communicate between an activity and the fragment that sits on top of it, I want new data (image/text - retrieved from the db) to be passed into the frag every time an onclick occurs (onclick is in the activity). I made a simple interface to test (let me know if this is not suitable for images or if it is too slow or inefficient), and I am trying to have it included in my fragment so when an onclick occurs the fragment changes the image and the text.

Here is the simple interface code:

```
public interface FragmentCommunicator {
    public void passDataToFragment(String someValue);
}
```

Here is the activity code:

```
public class RandomActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActivityCommunicator {

    //viewpager adapter
    private PageAdapter mAdapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    //interface through which communication is made to fragment
    public FragmentCommunicator fragmentCommunicator;

    //Buttons for yes, no, skip
    Button btnYesRandom, btnNoRandom, btnSkipRandom;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_random);

        //set buttons
        btnYesRandom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnYesRandom);

        // Initializing pager
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.random_pager);

        //calling bundle to attach data to fragment
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");

        // set Fragmentclass Arguments
        RandomFragment randFrag = new  RandomFragment();
        randFrag.setArguments(bundle);

        //Setting up fragment
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        mAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),  new UserUpVotesFragment(), randFrag, new UserDownVotesFragment());
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        // Here you would declare which page to visit on creation
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // Check if this is the page you want.
                if(position !=1) {
                    //swiping to the right
                    if(position == 0) {
                        Log.e("Swiping", "SWIPING TO THE Right BUT RESET ERR");
                        getIntent().removeExtra("edttext");
                    }

                    //swiping to the left
                    if(position == 2) {
                        Log.e("Swiping", "SWIPING TO THE left BUT RESET ERR");
                    }

                    // RandomFragment randomFrag = (RandomFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fra);

                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                }
            }
        });

        btnYesRandom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if(fragmentCommunicator != null)
                    fragmentCommunicator.passDataToFragment("Hi from FragmentActivity");
            }
        });
    }
```

Code for Fragment:

```
public class RandomFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //call data from activity bundle
        String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_random, container, false);

        RelativeLayout random_frag_layout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.random_frag_layout);

        activityButton = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imagehere);
        //setRetainInstance(true);

        texthere = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.texthere);
        texthere.setText(strtext);

        return rootView;
    }

    //FragmentCommunicator interface implementation
    public void passDataToFragment(String someValue){
        activityAssignedValue = someValue;
        Log.e("ACTIVITY", activityAssignedValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have only one fragment, then you can access it directly and send any data just via method: make your fragment a field and call your `passDataToFragment()` on it from activity.

To access an activity from fragment, call `((RandomActivity)getActivity()).activityMethod()`

Comment: Is this added in the onCreateView or where exactly in the fragment? I want it to be able to be called when a button is clicked on the activity side by the way... if you can show me sample code or tell me where in the fragment exactly it has to be called

Comment: Also, if I told the frag new data, would I be calling the imageview and textview in the method to be changed to the new data, or how do I "inflate" the new view while removing the old?

Comment: Calling a fragment is performed from `onClick()` in your activity, just call a fragment instead of communicator. And yes, you can call activity from fragment in fragment's `onCreateView()` to check the state before inflating. And the last: you can update views directly without reinflating.

Answer (score 0):

What is `ActivityCommunicator`?

If you wish to go down this route have your `RandomActivity` class implement the `FragmentCommunicator` interface, which should either be declared as an inner-public interface in the `RandomFragment` class say, or publicly (or package local) in its own file.

Comment: Oh it is just the same a fragment but talks from the fragment back to the activity... Is there a better way I am willing to go the most efficient route as I am going to be passing in pictures and text together constantly?